# Nginx redirect for a subdomain

Tags: docker, nginx

does anyone know how the interaction works in Nginx?
I currently have a subdomain, let's call it subdomain1, I want to change it to subdomain2.
To be more specific.
I run everything in a docker container and my certificate will be for subdomain2. And there will be no more servers with subdomain1.
I want to keep the traffic from google for subdomain1, but the name is not appropriate anymore and it needs to be changed to subdomain2.
Does something like this work? Will there be any issues?

```
server {
    server_name subdomain1.mydomain.com;
    return 301 http://www.subdomain2.mydomain.com/$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nassocci and welcome here :) You have no `location / { }` in which your redirection should be nested. Beware that 301 is a permanent redirection. For testing purpose, I suggest you to use 302 instead.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thank you, very much.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that could match :

```
server {
        listen 8066;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            rewrite (.*)$ http://www.google.com$1 redirect;
        }
}
```

8066 is for my test purpose to redirect to google.com.
If y try `localhost:8066/foo`, I go to `https://www.google.com/foo`
Note that `redirect` keyword makes it temporary. For a permanent redirection, use `permanent` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach will work. Following points might be helpful:

1. Since you want not to have any server for subdomain1 but in this redirection you need to ensure that subdomain1 also pointing to the same server where you have hosted subdomain2
2. use of $scheme
   `server { server_name subdomain1.mydomain.com; return 301 $scheme://subdomain2.mydomain.com$request_uri; }`
3. Generally people avoid using www before sub-domain.domain.com (you may refer this also)

Answer (score 0):

Section `server` in nginx has two required parameters `listen` and `server_name`. Add `listen` to your config and it will work

Man about server https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server

Example

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name _;
    return 301 http://www.google.com/$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps as the question already added details like `server_name subdomain1.mydomain.com` you could include those details? More information links also tend to work better at the end of an answer, thanks!